# Incorrect plural form for bounty interval

Tags: bug, android-app, bounties, plurals

The Android app shows a banner about bounty with an incorrect plural form:

> [image: bounty banner]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1635123498b3d)

Comment: Giant S incoming ...

Comment: @Glorfindel Giant (image) has been reduced :)

Comment: I meant [this Giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791/295232).

Comment: [uh, oh! meme-sign!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63791)

Comment: I propose "meme-sign" to be a new meme. Is that allowed? Saves the time of going through the organic re-use and subsequent rise to the collective consciousness. Because it is already meme-e:  References MST3K - "movie sign" , which references Dune - "worm sign".