# Plural issue for questions closed as duplicates

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, ios-app, plurals

Self explained (I hope) picture below:

> [image: 1 answers]

- App Version: 1.6.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/315822 (Just thought you should be warned.)

Comment: [Related post for Android-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271890/312043)

Comment: @zondo I have already been notified about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289791/incorrect-plural-form-for-bounty-interval#comment940891_289791) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.